# imported file in Python cannot find its own imported file

Tags: python

The imported file cannot locate its own import file

In main.py:

```
from subfolder import get_data
```

In subfolder\get_data.py:

```
import get_info #in subfoler

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_info'
```

How to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `from . import get_info`

Comment: do you have an empty `__init__.py` file in your "subfolder"?

Answer (score -1):

***You can change your path as below code and try :***

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from subfolder import get_data
```

Comment: Can I set to find the module in the same folder by default for all files?

Comment: Yes! You can do something like : `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/add_your_path_over_here"`